# A lot of vs Much/Many

Tags: quantifiers

I was searching for difference between *a lot of* and *Much* and came across following rules([See here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers))

> We usually use a lot of and lots of rather than muchand many in
>   informal affirmative clauses:
>
> There are *a lot of* monuments and *a lot of* historic buildings in
>   Rome.
>
> Not: There are *many* monuments and *many* historic buildings in Rome.
>
> She gave me *a lot of* information.
>
> Not: She gave me *much* information.

But it is not clear to me where to use a lot and where to use much/many. Why much or many is wrong in above sentence.

Comment: As the text says, we tend to use "a lot of" in **informal** situations.  As a rough guide, use "a lot of" in speech, apart from formal presentations, and "much/many" in writing.

Comment: @JavaLatte mena if informal perspective is concerned, both are correct

Comment: In an informal setting, for example conversation with friends, use of much/many would sound strange. Indeed, there are several even less formal terms that one might use in speech, for example " heaps of", "loads of", "a shed load of". A typical sentence might be "John can buy the next round- he's got loads of money!"